# Calculate probability of union of events

Tags: probability

> Let $A$ and $B$ be events in sample space $S$ such that $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(A' \cap B') = \frac{1}{3}$. Find $ P(A\cup B')$.

I found that $P(A\cup B) =  \frac{2}{3}$ and $P(A' \cap B)$ [that is $P(B$ only$)$] $= \frac{1}{6}$. Now I am unable to find $P(A \cap B)$ which will give me the answer.

[image]

I am stuck here. Could anyone help me in getting the answer.

Comment: Did you try drawing a Venn diagram for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of your Venn diagram (i.e. the "required answer") is not correct. It should look as follows:

[image]

we need to compute the probability of the area colored in orange. Since it is given that

[image]

it follows that the desired probability equals

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{6}.$$

Comment: That's correct. Thanks